# Работа с Navigation Drawer. Android Studio.

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Извините за убогость вопроса, но я только начал обучение в данной среде.
В процессе разработки приложения на Android (в Android Studio) вылез такой вопрос - как осуществить корректный переход между активностями при выборе определенного пункта меню в Navigation Drawer.
Допустим, я создал 2 активности при помощи мастера, где и был выбран метод навигации "Navigation Drawer". В результате мы имеем 3 класса. Допустим у 1-го имя "Advices", у 2-го "Input", а у 3-го "NavigationDrawerFragment" (Он был создан непосредственно самой средой).
Я пытался реализовать переход на активность "Input". Для этого в классе "Advices", в процедуре "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected" я написал следующий код:

***int y = position + 1;
if (y == 2)
   { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Input.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
   }***

Так вот, переход на активность осуществляется, но при этом меню дальше работает не корректно. Можете что-то посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте фрагменты ─ [пример от гугла Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) использование activity при использование Navigation Drawer не корректно

Answer (score 0):

Грузите данные в фрагменты, как это сделано в документации. 
Пример можно скачать здесь: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html